# Subdirectorio react dentro de wordpress da 404

Tags: wordpress, apache

Tengo una web con wordpress y quiero utilizar un subdirectorio para montar una app react.(ejemplo.com/react)

El problema es que al navegar en ejemplo.com/react/1 me da error 404 con la plantilla del wordpress.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Buenas! Tengo un wordpress tambien con un subdirectorio como tu para mi app y funciona perfectamente. Solo muestra un 404 con la plantilla de wordpress cuando hay un error en la ruta. Has comprovado que sea la correcta? El 1 que pones al final de la ruta es un archivo con extension tipo php?

Comment: gracias por responder tan rápido @Ferran, creo que el problema era apache, pues he seguido estos pasos https://stanko.github.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/ y ya me va perfectamente, gracias!